# How can I get back the old download UI in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome recently changed the download page (when you press `CTRL + J`) and it now has a material look, with a lot of wasted spaces on two sides.

How can I get back the old, non-material-design download page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `chrome://flags/` and find `Enable Material Design downloads`, then choose `Disabled` in the dropdown. Restart Chrome.

[image]